# Question about google Apps and MX records

Tags: domain, g-suite, mx-record, redirection

i have just signed up with google apps and have successfully re-routed my mx records to google.

I also have a second domain that i occasionally use and would like to know if i can route the mx records for that domain to google as well. If i do will google accept the messages?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the new domain name to your Google Apps account; only then will GA accept mail for that domain name.

When you log into your Google Apps management page, the first thing underneath the menubar ("Dashboard", "Users and Groups") will be a big blue box with the name of your organization, your domain name, and then two links, "Manage account information" and "domain names".  Click "domain names", and you can add a new domain name.

Answer (score 1):

Not unless you've configured Google to accept mail for that second domain as well.

Comment: do i need to sign up that domain? would you be able to tell me where to add those details?